# PHP digits to string for preg_match

Tags: php, regex, casting

Thanks in advance, I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple. I have some numerical zip codes that I need to run through a function...however, I need to validate that the input is a five digit string. But, no matter how I try to cast the number to string, it's failing. Is there some other way I should be encoding or formatting?:

```
<?php
$code=07307;
$wrapped_code='07307';
$castcode=(string)$code;
$strcode=''.$code;

echo (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $code))?'success with code<br/>':'code failed, saw:'.$code."<br/>";
echo (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $wrapped_code))?'success with wrapped_code<br/>':'wrapped_code failed, saw:'.$wrapped_code."<br/>";
echo (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $castcode))?'success with castcode<br/>':'castcode failed, saw:'.$castcode."<br/>";
echo (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $strcode))?'success with strcode<br/>':'strcode failed, saw:'.$strcode."<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
echo 07307;
```

You will find, counter-intuitively, that you get the result `3783`. This is because numbers starting in `0` are treated as octals, that is, in base 8. So when you cast `07307` to a string, you get `"3783"`. If leading zeros are important, you should be using a string in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I needed to work with it as a string, and it turned out I had a complicating error: I was importing the initial values from a CSV file, and when the column of interest was the LAST, I wasn't properly removing newlines...I don't know why that mattered for this aspect of it, but when I added a dummy column after it, things behaved as they should.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said you want to achieve, I think you'd be better off using [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) and [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen), as `is_numeric` checks whether a variable is a number or a numeric string.